# Refreshing bearer token and using AccessTokenPlugin

Tags: swift, swift4, alamofire, swift5, moya

For many of my endpoints, I require a bearer token to be passed with the request to authenticate the user. Because of that, I also need to refresh the user's token if it expires.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54936080/refreshing-auth-token-with-moya) to start me along, but I'm still unsure about some things and how to implement them.

As the answer to the question above suggests, I've created an extension for `MoyaProvider`:

```
extension MoyaProvider {
    convenience init(handleRefreshToken: Bool) {
        if handleRefreshToken {
            self.init(requestClosure: MoyaProvider.endpointResolver())
        } else {
            self.init()
        }
    }

    static func endpointResolver() -> MoyaProvider<Target>.RequestClosure {
        return { (endpoint, closure) in
            //Getting the original request
            let request = try! endpoint.urlRequest()

            //assume you have saved the existing token somewhere                
            if (#tokenIsNotExpired#) {                   
                // Token is valid, so just resume the original request
                closure(.success(request))
                return
            }

            //Do a request to refresh the authtoken based on refreshToken
            authenticationProvider.request(.refreshToken(params)) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let response):
                    let token = response.mapJSON()["token"]
                    let newRefreshToken = response.mapJSON()["refreshToken"]
                    //overwrite your old token with the new token
                    //overwrite your old refreshToken with the new refresh token

                    closure(.success(request)) // This line will "resume" the actual request, and then you can use AccessTokenPlugin to set the Authentication header
                case .failure(let error):
                    closure(.failure(error)) //something went terrible wrong! Request will not be performed
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I've also created an extension for `TargetType`, which looks like this:

```
import Moya

public protocol TargetTypeExtension: TargetType, AccessTokenAuthorizable {}

public extension TargetTypeExtension {

    var baseURL: URL { return URL(string: Constants.apiUrl)! }

    var headers: [String: String]? { return nil }

    var method: Moya.Method { return .get }

    var authorizationType: AuthorizationType { return .bearer }

    var sampleData: Data { return Data() }
}
```

Here is one such implementation of it:

```
import Moya

public enum Posts {
    case likePost(postId: Int)
    case getComments(postId: Int)
}

extension Posts: TargetTypeExtension {
    public var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .likePost(_): return "posts/like"
        case .getComments(_): return "posts/comments"
        }
    }

    public var authorizationType: AuthorizationType {
        switch self {
        case .likePost(_): return .bearer
        case .getComments(_): return .none
        }
    }

    public var method: Moya.Method {
        switch self {
        case .likePost, .getComments:
            return .post
        }
    }

    public var task: Task {
        switch self {
        case let .likePost(postId):
            return .requestParameters(parameters: ["postId": postId], encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        case let .getComments(postId):
            return .requestParameters(parameters: ["postId": postId], encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, my `likePost` request requires a bearer token, while my `getComments` request does not.

So I have a few questions:

1. How would I modify my `MoyaProvider` extension to utilize Moya's `AccessTokenPlugin`, [found here](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/docs/Authentication.md#access-token-auth)?
2. How would I modify my `MoyaProvider` extension to NOT require a bearer token if the `AuthorizationType` is `.none` for a specific request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I did with custom moya provider and RxSwift if you are using RxSwift you can take reference, it will not directly fit into yor code!!

```
 extension Reactive where Base: MyMoyaProvider {
        func request(_ token: Base.Target, callbackQueue: DispatchQueue? = nil) -> Single<Response> {

    return Single.create { [weak base] single in

        var pandingCancelable:Cancellable?
        /// reschedule original request
        func reschedulCurrentRequest() {
            base?.saveRequest({
                pandingCancelable = base?.request(token, callbackQueue: callbackQueue, progress: nil) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case.success(let response):
                        single(.success(response))
                    case .failure(let error):
                        single(.error(error))
                    }
                }
            })
        }

        func refreshAccessToken(refreshToken:String) -> Cancellable? {
            base?.isRefreshing = true /// start retrieveing refresh token
            return base?.request(.retriveAccessToken(refreshToken: refreshToken), completion: { _ in
                base?.isRefreshing = false /// end retrieveing refresh token
                base?.executeAllSavedRequests()
            })
        }

        if (base?.isRefreshing ?? false) {
            reschedulCurrentRequest()
            return Disposables.create { pandingCancelable?.cancel() }
        }

        let cancellableToken = base?.request(token, callbackQueue: callbackQueue, progress: nil) { result in
            switch result {
            case let .success(response):
                if !(base?.isRefreshing ?? false), !token.isOAuth2TokenRefreshType, response.statusCode == TokenPlugin.CODE_UNAUTHORIZED, let refreshToken = token.getRefreshToken {
                    reschedulCurrentRequest()
                    _ = refreshAccessToken(refreshToken: refreshToken)
                } else if (base?.isRefreshing ?? false) {
                   reschedulCurrentRequest()
                } else {
                    single(.success(response))
                }
            case let .failure(error):
                single(.error(error))
            }
        }

        return Disposables.create {
            cancellableToken?.cancel()
        }
    }
}
}
```

CustomProvider:

```
class MyMoyaProvider: MoyaProvider<MyServices> {

var isRefreshing = false
private var pandingRequests: [DispatchWorkItem] = []

func saveRequest(_ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // Save request to DispatchWorkItem array
    pandingRequests.append( DispatchWorkItem {
        block()
    })
}

func executeAllSavedRequests() {
    pandingRequests.forEach({ DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: $0); })
    pandingRequests.removeAll()
}
}

extension TargetType {
    var isOAuth2TokenRefreshType: Bool { return false }
    var getRefreshToken:String? {  return nil }
}
```